# Writing output files at runtime Xamarin.UITest Test app

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.uitest

We are using Xamarin.UITest I have added a backdoor method only called (.Invoked(string)) from My test - I am using Visual Studio for Mac and iOS Simulator.

I want to run the debugger in iOS app and the iOS test at same time.
It seems to only debugger the Test app. I tried an additional attach to a process that it Invokes

The Method in App Delegate looks like this:

[image]

I thought I could pause the debugger before the Invoke call and attach the process. It does not break. What do I need to do?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Hey Mark could you please explain your question a bit differently?

Comment: If you want to run two debuggers at the same time, can’t you launch 2 instances of Visual Studio at the same time on the same computer and just run the apps with your specific config from the separate instances.